# Allow user to download his own file after the purchase

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to develop an App which allows to purchase a file (which is a kind of particular invoice) based on user form input. I'm using React for frontend and Node for backend.

Basically this is the app flow:

- the user fill the form
- the user clicks on `Proceed` button
- a modal window is opened which contains the `PayPal Express Checkout button`
- the user complete the transaction
- the user is redirected to the `Success page`
- the user received an email with the file created and he can also download the file from the link present in the Success page

**It "works" but there are 2 main problems:**

- The file generated is overwritten on every transaction order: how can I save every file generated and allow each one different user to download only his generated file? Should I create a sorta of unique URL to get that single file.
- The transactions are not stored: when should I store them? On `createPayPalOrder` time? Or after the approve?

---

This is the Frontend (just the Checkout)

[image: Edit stoic-sea-edbv3o]

This is the Backend

[image: Edit fervent-shadow-fr90ig]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need to store that file on S3 bucket or any other place you like.

Long answer:
when the transaction starts you need to save it in the database with its state as `init` and once the transaction gets approved you then need to change the state of that transaction to `success` in case of failure `failed`.

now as the transaction gets approved and then you created the invoice you need to upload it on the s3 bucket and store its URL in the transaction table.

and then share that link with the user.

now on every new transaction new invoice will get generated and it will be stored on s3 bucket and you can have all the transactions created by that particular use in the database.